# Почему замуж выходят?

Tags: этимология

Интересно, вот мужчина - женится, а женщина - ВЫХОДИТ замуж. Почему именно выходит? Имеется в виду, что она покидает свой дом?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вы правы, хотя я не уверена, что это исторически обязательное условие брака. Тут скорее буквально «за мужем» - то есть за его спиной, под защитой и покровительством. Или «за мужа» - то есть во всем следовать за мужем, быть с ним и на его стороне.

Comment: @behemothus: Насчет свободы не скажите. Замужняя женщина действительно становилась в зависимое положение от воли супруга, но нужно учитывать, что до замужества она зачастую была в родительским доме пустым местом, была лишена права голоса, права выбирать свою судьбу. А замужняя женщина (или вдова) имела уважение, почет в обществе, могла заслужить признание ее мудрости и опытности. При этом она, правда, могла быть в доме мужа на положении рабы, но все же возможностей у нее было гораздо больше.

Comment: @Doctrina, смотря за кого замуж выйдет. Вообще если социальную значимость приобретать, то в патриархальном обществе надо не замуж, а в монахини идти. Девица в отличии от замужней могла ходить на гуляния, игры, как правило была меньше загружена работой, к тому же не была беременной. Жена приобретала прав больше чем обязанностей только тогда, когда становилась старшей женщиной в семье, а этот этап у 16-18-летней девушки наступал нескоро.

Comment: Вы сейчас современный взгляд на историю семьи пересказываете. И непонятно, за какую эпоху. А что касается этимогонии, то слово древнее и в момент своего образования (ну никак не позже Крещения Руси) все это воспринималось не так. Приставка "за" до сих пор обозначает присваивание, прикрепление, фиксацию с пассивной ролью объекта (забирать, закабалять, закрепощать), соответственно "замуж" - в собственность мужа, "замуживать".

Answer (score 1):

У В.О. Ключевского находим: "Хождение жениха за невестой, заменившее умычку, в свою очередь сменилось приводом невесты к жениху с получением вена или с выдачей приданого, почему законная жена в языческой Руси называлась водимою. От этих двух форм брака, хождения жениха и привода невесты, идут, по-видимому, выражения брать замуж и выдавать замуж: язык запомнил много старины, свеянной временем с людской памяти. Умычка, вено, в смысле откупа за умычку, вено, как продажа невесты, хождение за невестой, привод невесты с уплатой вена и потом с выдачей приданого — все эти сменявшие одна другую формы брака были последовательными моментами разрушения родовых связей, подготовлявшими взаимное сближение родов. Брак размыкал род. так сказать, с обоих концов, облегчая не толь¬ко выход из рода, но и приобщение к нему. Родственники жениха и невесты становились своими людьми друг для друга, свояками: свойство сделалось видом родства. Значит, брак уже в языческую пору роднил чуждые друг другу роды. В первичном, нетронутом своем составе род представляет замкнутый союз, недоступный для чужаков: невеста из чужого рода порывала родственную связь со своими кровными родичами, но, став женой, не роднила их с родней своего мужа.

Приданое служило основой отдельного имущества жены; появлением приданого началось юридическое определение положения дочери или сестры в семье, ее правового отношения к семейному имуществу. По Русской Правде сестра при братьях не наследница; но братья обязаны устроить ее судьбу, выдать замуж, «како си могут», с посильным приданым. Как накладная обязанность, которая ложится на наследство, приданое не могло быть приятным для наследников институтом. Это сказалось в одной пословице, выразительно изображающей различные чувства, возбуждаемые в членах семьи появлением зятя: «Тесть любит честь, зять любит взять, теща любит дать, а шурин глаза щурит, дать не хочет». При отсутствии братьев дочь — полноправная наследница отцовского имущества в землевладельческой служилой семье и сохраняет право на честь крестьянского имущества, если осталась после отца незамужней. Все отношения по наследованию заключены в тесные пределы простой семьи; наследники из боковых не предусматриваются, как случайные участники в наследстве. Строя такую семью и заботливо очищая ее от остатков языческого родового союза, христианская церковь имела для того бытовой материал, заготовленный ещё в языческую пору, между прочим, в браке с приданым".

Answer (score 0):

> Имеется в виду, что она покидает свой дом?

Да, именно так. "Дом" - не просто в смысле "жилище", но семья, родственники. Выйдя замуж девушка ***выходила*** из под родительской опеки, становилась членом другой семьи. Хотя сам факт того, что в обороте оказался отраженной именно это сторона жизни, весьма любопытен. Видимо, менталитет наших предков сказался. Сравните: "выдать замуж" - явно в значении "вручить", "отдать".

Касательно слова "замуж". Не думаю, что тут так все красиво. "Замуж" - это не а смысле "за щит" (защита) или "следовать за". Это скорее как "за забор", "за ограду". Замужняя женщина теряла очень многое в плане и без того куцей личной свободы.